# Uniform continuous with simple properties

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-continuity

$f$ is a map from $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Let $f$ be continous and assume $f$ is both uniformly contiuous on $(-\infty,0]$ and $[0,\infty)$ . Show that $f$ is uniformly continuous on all of $\mathbb{R}$.

I would've thought that the function $f$ is actually uniformly continuous over all the real numbers since it is in both the intervals $(-\infty,0]$ and $[0,\infty)$. I guess the "problem" arises on $f(0)$. Do I have to use that $f(x)$ and $f(y)$ for $x<0<y$ somehow and $f(0)$?

How would such a proof be done?

Comment: @TheoBendit yes! Fixed now :-)!

Answer (score 2):

We wish to show, for all $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists some $\delta > 0$ such that, for all $x, y \in \Bbb{R}$ (might as well assume $x < y$),
$$|x - y| < \delta \implies |f(x) - f(y)| < \varepsilon.$$
As you seem to be aware, there are three cases of note: either $x < y \le 0$, $0 \le x < y$, or $x < 0 < y$. We need a $\delta$ small enough to cover whichever case it happens to be. The tricky one seems to be the third case: $x < 0 < y$, which we can cover using continuity at $0$.

Because $f$ is continuous at $0$, there exists some $\delta_1 > 0$ such that
$$|x| < \delta_1 \implies |f(x) - f(0)| < \frac{\varepsilon}{2}.$$
If we have $|x - y| < \delta_1$ with $x < 0 < y$, then
$$|x| = -x < y - x = |x - y| < \delta,$$
and similarly,
$$|y| = y < y - x = |x - y| < \delta.$$
Therefore, for such $x$ and $y$ we have
$$|f(x) - f(0)| < \frac{\varepsilon}{2} \text{ and } |f(y) - f(0)| < \frac{\varepsilon}{2}.$$
Thus,
$$|f(x) - f(y)| \le |f(x) - f(0)| + |f(0) - f(y)| < \varepsilon.$$
This covers the $x < 0 < y$ case. To complete the full proof, let $\delta_2 > 0$ such that
$$|x - y| < \delta_2 \text{ and } x, y \le 0 \implies |f(x) - f(y)| < \varepsilon$$
and $\delta_3 > 0$ such that
$$|x - y| < \delta_3 \text{ and } x, y \ge 0 \implies |f(x) - f(y)| < \varepsilon.$$
Then
$$|x - y| < \min\{\delta_1, \delta_2, \delta_3\} \implies |f(x) - f(y)| < \varepsilon,$$
as required.

Comment: You mean $\delta _3$ in the second last equation right?

Comment: after you denote "$\delta_3 >0$"

Comment: @mathstudent23 Yes, that's right.

Comment: @mathstudent23 I notice that you unaccepted my answer, and I was just wondering why? Someone also recently un-upvoted my answer to this question, and the whole thing has me wondering: is there a problem with my answer that I'm just not seeing? I've had people unaccept my answers before, but the fact that this happened shortly after an un-upvote (which I've never had before) has me concerned!

Comment: Unfortunately I was told the approach was not correct this way and got it wrong. However I still wanted to see the approach and method hence https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4063851/uniform-f-is-uniformly-continuous/4063856?noredirect=1#comment8396230_4063856

Comment: I removed the acceptance just in case untill I know if it is indeed correct but it does seem to dissagree with the answers in the linked thread. Feel free to edit your answer or keep it this way and I will take a look and gladly accept! Thanks for the help.

Comment: @mathstudent23 My answer is basically the same as Jose's and Kavi's, with perhaps a little more detail. My construction is identical to Kavi's. I was quite sure that my proof was sound, and seeing it presented again independently by someone else is reassuring.

Comment: I do not know what the problematic areas are then as I was just told it was wrong. Could it be that we pick 3 deltas assigned to the delta? Could you perhaps write explicitly where each case is covered as that would help me a lot!