# Uniform $f$ is uniformly continuous

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity, uniform-continuity

$f$ is a map from $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Let $f$ be continous and assume $f$ is both uniformly contiuous on $(-\infty,0]$ and $[0,\infty)$ . Show that $f$ is uniformly continuous on all of $\mathbb{R}$.

I thought that the function $f$ is actually uniformly continuous over all the real numbers since it is in both the intervals $(-\infty,0]$ and $[0,\infty)$. I guess the "problem" arises on $f(0)$.

I have been trying to prove this for hours upon hours now but I just do not get it even though I get the definitions and that you should assign 3 $\delta$‘s to cover every case (I think) and then a $\delta$ to be the minimum of one of thoes. I can not show how to pick the $\delta$’s as this is hard for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\epsilon >0$. There exist $\delta_1$ abnd $\delta_2>0$ such that

1. $|f(x)-f(y)| <\epsilon/2$ if $x, y \leq 0$ and $|x-y| \leq \delta_1$
2. $|f(x)-f(y)| <\epsilon/2$ if $x, y \geq 0$ and $|x-y| \leq \delta_2$

Let $\delta=\min\{\delta_1,\delta_2\}$.
Suppose $|x-y| <\delta$. We claim that  $|f(x)-f(y)| <\epsilon$. The only case where you face difficulty is when one of $x,y$ is $\leq 0$ and the other is $\geq 0$. Supose $x \leq 0$ and $y \geq 0$. Then $|f(x)-f(y)| \leq |f(x)-f(0)|+|f(0)-f(y)|<\epsilon /2+\epsilon /2=\epsilon$.

Comment: I am almost following this. I am confused about 2 things: shoulddn’t we pick 3 (or 4 $\delta$‘S to be the minimum or are the 2 last cases covered from the first two cases?

Comment: @mathstudent23 Given any two real numbers $x$ and $y$ you have the following possibilities: a) $x\geq 0, y\geq 0$, b) $x\leq 0,y\leq 0$, c) $x\geq 0, y\leq 0$, d) $x\leq 0, y\geq 0$. In case a) use the fact that $\delta <\delta_1$.  In case b) use the fact that $\delta <\delta_2$.  In the other two cases use the inequality I stated in the answer.

Comment: May I ask why it is not strickt inequalities for the $\delta$'s in the beginning in (1) and (2)?

Comment: @mathstudent23 That makes no difference to the proof. You can use strict inequalities if you prefer.

Comment: I am still a bit unsure about why you write "we claim that..." but then do not proceed to do anything with that claim?

Comment: @mathstudent23 I showed that $|x-y|<\delta$ implies that $|f(x)-f(y)| <\epsilon$.

Comment: Okay so this is actually the final proof if I am following you correctly?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: So case 1 and 2 are covered in the start and 3 and 4 are covered in the last part where $\delta$ is the minimum of the other 2

Answer (score 0):

Given $\varepsilon>0$, take $\delta>0$ such that $|x-y|\implies\bigl|f(x)-f(y)\bigr|<\frac\varepsilon2$ both on $[0,\infty)$ and on $(-\infty,0]$. Then if $x,y\in\Bbb R$ are such that $|x-y|<\delta$ and if $x\leqslant0\leqslant y$, then$$\bigl|f(x)-f(y)\bigr|\leqslant\bigl|f(x)-f(0)\bigr|+\bigl|f(0)-f(y)\bigr|<\varepsilon$$and you have a similar argument if $x\geqslant0\geqslant y$.